# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when I try to build a MultiDiGraph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I dont know why there are always some problems when I build the following codes.

```
df_agent = pd.read_csv('agent_total.csv') 

G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df_agent, 'move from id', 'move to id' ,edge_attr=True ,create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph() )
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sublimetext3\code\analyse.py", line 11, in <module>
    G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df_agent, 'move from id', 'move to id' ,edge_attr=True ,create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph() )
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\networkx\convert_matrix.py", line 211, in from_pandas_dataframe
    g.add_edge(row[src_i], row[tar_i], {i:row[j] for i, j in edge_i})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\multidigraph.py", line 344, in add_edge
    keydict[key] = datadict
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

`agent_total.csv` is my CSV file. I also tried that if I remove `edge_attr=True` or remove `create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph()`, there isn't any problem, but if not, the error is as above.

when I use df_agent.head(),the output is as follow

```
transfer id  player id  agent id  move from id  move to id
0       296662        911      1181          8553        3165
1       279324        911      1181          1402        8553
2       211933        911      1181          1876        1402
3       161075        911      1181           515        1876
4       125178        911      1181           996         515
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `df_agent.head()`?

Comment: I have edited my question, please look at it again.